# Do both of them correct? & "Are both of them correct?"

Tags: grammaticality

Any grammatical errors in these sentences? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is all right, but the first one should be

> Do both of them *correctly*.

because you need an adverb,not an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

"Are both of them correct?" is a grammatical sentence. "Correct", in this case, is an adjective.

Unless you are talking about teaching assistants who "correct" students' homework ("correct" as a verb), "*Do* both of them correct?" is not grammatical.